# What is the unit for MathNet distance calcuations?

Tags: latitude-longitude, math.net

Given the following code I would like to compute the distance in Miles or Kilometers:

```
Point2D point1 = new Point2D(47.6062, -122.3321); // Seattle
Point2D point2 = new Point2D(37.7749, -122.4194); // San Francisco

double distance = point1.DistanceTo(point2);
```

After reviewing the [documentation](https://spatial.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Spatial.Euclidean/index.htm), it is not clear what type of unit is returned. I see there is a units section in the [documentation](https://spatial.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Spatial.Units/index.htm).

However, it is not clear what the unit of distance would be:

- Angle
- AngleUnit
- Degrees
- IAngleUnit
- Radians

Also, given the returned unit is one of the items listed above.  How, would you handle the conversion to miles / kilometers?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://spatial.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Spatial.Euclidean/Point2D.htm#DistanceTo) `double Point2D.DistanceTo(Point2D otherPoint)` **"Finds the straight line distance to another point"**. That means you are supposed to be on a **plain**. The result units are the same as ones used to create `Point2D` objects. But that has nothing to do with finding distances on the surface of the Earth. What you need is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var earthRadius = 6371; // km
    var seattle = GetVector(47.6062, -122.3321);
    var sanFrancisco = GetVector(37.7749, -122.4194);
    var angle = seattle.AngleTo(sanFrancisco);
    var distance = angle.Radians * earthRadius;
    Console.WriteLine(distance);
}


private static UnitVector3D GetVector(double lat, double lon)
{
    var tmp = UnitVector3D.ZAxis;
    var latitude = Angle.FromDegrees(lat);
    var longitude = Angle.FromDegrees(lon);
    var vector = UnitVector3D.XAxis.Rotate(tmp, longitude);
    tmp = UnitVector3D.ZAxis.CrossProduct(vector);
    vector = vector.Rotate(tmp, latitude);
    return vector;
}
```

The result is:

```
1093,21376382715
```

[Check it is correct](https://www.google.com/search?q=seattle+san+francisco+distance+straight).

To get miles change `earthRadius` value to one in miles.

**Update:**

`GetVector` can be implemented another way:

```
private static UnitVector3D north = UnitVector3D.ZAxis;
private static UnitVector3D east = UnitVector3D.XAxis;
private static Point3D northPole = UnitVector3D.ZAxis.ToPoint3D();
private static Point3D southPole = (-1 * UnitVector3D.ZAxis).ToPoint3D();

private static UnitVector3D GetVector(double lat, double lon)
{
    var longitude = Angle.FromDegrees(lon);
    var direction = east.Rotate(north, longitude);
    var meridian = Circle3D.FromPoints(northPole, southPole, direction.ToPoint3D());
    var normal = meridian.Axis;
    var latitude = Angle.FromDegrees(lat);
    return direction.Rotate(normal, latitude);
}
```